# How do I overcome this error in Android studio, my network has no problem but don't know they say network?

Tags: android, android-studio, project

I get an error saying "Gradles dependency cache may be corrupt "
That it's created due to network timeout but my network is perfectly. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: make sure you are not behind any proxy, you can try invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Maybe you have Grandle in offline mode (there is a symbol like "=/=" on the right)